# Following a link to search for a name in a list

Tags: python, url, tags, href

I am in the process of  extracting the href = values from the anchor tags, and then scanning for a tag that is in a certain position relative to the first name in the list. I need to follow the link for this until I reach the last name.  I have tried running what I have, but I keep getting "Montgomery" in the url I get after running. Have a missed something with this?

**This is what I have been working on:**

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urllink = "https://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Fikret.html"
position = int(raw_input("Enter the position:"))
count_ = int(raw_input("Enter a count:"))

def main(urllink, position, count_):
    for _ in xrange(count_):
        page = urllib.urlopen(urllink).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
        tags = soup.findAll('a')
        link = tags[position-1].get('href', None)
    return link

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print main(urllink, position, count_)
```

**Here is the sample output:**

```
$ python solution.py 
Enter URL: http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/ ... /known_by_Fikret.html
Enter count: 4
Enter position: 3
Retrieving: http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/ ... /known_by_Fikret.html
Retrieving: http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/ ... /known_by_Montgomery.html
Retrieving: http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/ ... /known_by_Mhairade.html
Retrieving: http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/ ... /known_by_Butchi.html
Last Url: http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/ ... /known_by_Anayah.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  I accidently entered the wrong count when prompted.  This is no longer a question.  However, please feel free to leave some feedback about my code if you want.